# how to make calendar not to redirect on current month

Tags: javascript

this is a `fullcalendar.js` script, I am using `fullCalendar.min.js`.

I have one problem, here I have used a username filter, and when I am on January and then select a name from the dropdown filter, then it automatically redirects me to the current month. Then every time I have to click the Previous arrow.

How to solve this problem if I am currently on July month and select a username, so that it selects the name but doesn't redirect to current month.

Please help.

Below is my script's code:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            height: 350,
            contentHeight: 300,
            aspectRatio: 2,
            eventLimit: 6,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
            },
            defaultDate: '<?=date("Y-m-d")?>',
            navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            businessHours: false, // display business hours
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: [ // my data coming here with foreach loop
            ,
                    start: '',
                    overlap: false,

                    color: ,



            ],

        });

    });

</script>
```

A little help will really be appreciated.

//New Script

```
/* Previous button click ... */
        $('.fc-prev-button').click(function () {    
                var action = "prevMonth";
                var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
                var strView = view.name;
                var prevMonthDate = view.start;
                var d = new Date(prevMonthDate);
                var str = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm', d); 
                alert(str);
        });
        /* Next button click ... */
        $('.fc-next-button').click(function () {
                var action = "nextMonth";
                var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
                var strView = view.name;
                var nextMonthDate = view.start;
                var d = new Date(nextMonthDate);
                var str = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm', d);
                alert(str);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you switch to another user, you should also remember the current month or time in some way. Depending on your page, it can be in a cookie, in a JS variable, window.storage etc.

Then you can switch to your previously selected date as follows:

```
//for testing; in real case you need to load this from somewhere
var previousDate = moment("2016-01"); 

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', previousDate);
```

You will place this at the end of your code that does the switching from one user or another, or in the `viewRender`.

Comment: great K48 it worked :)  but please .how we can pass month dynamically which we have selected on calendar..

Comment: please see new script on my question 
inplace of alert i want to use gotodate function so that it display that month whenever i select the name from filter please help